# Java fillOval will not fill window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, render

** Please feel free to provide feedback on the process flow as well.  There is probably a better way to complete what I'm doing, I'm just not aware of it.

I have a Game class which extends a JPanel.  In the `paintComponent()` method it renders a different class based on the state of the game (menus).  Only the welcome screen paints across the entire window.  The others don't fill the window, even if I manually assign the coordinates of (0, 0, 1000, 1000) on a 640x480 window.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (state == State.WELCOME) {

        welcome.render(g);

    } else if (state == State.SELECTPOSITION) {

        selectPosition.render(g);

    } else if (state == State.SELECTSCENARIO) {

        selectScenario.render(g);
...
```

More states are listed with the same logic are listed under the `selectScenario()` line.

The `render()` methods of the first 2 are listed below:

```
welcome.render(g)

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Welcome", 50, 150);
}


selectPosition.render(g)

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

There is a red line approximately 50px high at the bottom of the screen during the SelectPosition screen.

Please let me know if you need more information.  I attempted to share only relevant lines.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `setBackground(Color c);`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The current colors are simply to help me determine if the windows are changing as expected.  I updated the JPanel logic to use setBackground(Color.[color]).  The same issue remains with the colored bar at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is.  Is there anything else in the paintComponent(Graphics g) method? Maybe you need to use this: [initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). (I don't really know how to use it)

Comment: Nothing else is in the paintComponent method.  My Game class extends JPanel and implements Runnable.  The run method is calculating frames and calling an update method 30 times per second.  The update method is calling repaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are unfamiliar with much of your code, your logic, and your program's structure, and you may wish to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to let us actually experience for ourselves what you are experiencing. But it sounds to me as if what you really want to do is swap views based on state such as can be accomplished using a CardLayout.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  You are right about the sscce.  I never know what to include and what to leave out of my examples.  I have researched CardLayout, and that sounds close to what I am looking for.  I'll try that.  Thank you.